# creating REST API in PHP PDO getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, pdo

I am following the following tutorial on creating a REST API:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqEONSbXeSQ&t=2s

Here is how I built the Connect class:

```
<?php
  class Connect extends PDO 
  {
    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct("mysql:host='xx.xxx.x.xx:4485';dbname='myDb'", 'myDb_user', 'myDb_password',
      array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
      $this->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $this->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }
  }
?>
```

Here is my index.php that contains the API class:

```
<?php
  require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';
  class API {
    function Select() {
      $db = new Connect;
      $users = array();
      $data = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users');
      $data->execute();
      while($OutputData = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $users[$OutputData['username']] = array(
          'username' => $OutputData['username'],
          'fullname' => $OutputData['fullname'],
          'email' => $OutputData['email']
        );
      }
    }
  }

  $API = new API;
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo $API->Select();
?>
```

Using the above, I am getting the following onscreen error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: 
getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\config.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\config.php(7): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host='xx....', 
'myDb_user', 'myDb_passwo...', Array)
#1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\index.php(5): Connect-&gt;__construct()
#2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\index.php(23): API-&gt;Select()
#3 {main}

Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No 
such host is known.  in C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\config.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\config.php(7): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host='xx....', 
'myDb_user', 'myDb_passwo...', Array)
#1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\index.php(5): Connect-&gt;__construct()
#2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\index.php(23): API-&gt;Select()
#3 {main}
thrown in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\config.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
```

This is my first time attempting to use a class for a connection.  I've used the same connection info with other sites and I have no problem connecting to the dB.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It can't resolve the host you're using for your database connection. Double-check the spelling.

Comment: Your provided host does not exist. Do you actually supply `xx.xxx.x.xx`? Also remove `'` from DNS string

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is related to [tag:api], [tag:class], [tag:oop], or [tag:pdo]  after all?

Comment: You seem to be trying to literally connect to `xx...`.

Comment: _Side note:_ You should only create one instance of your `Connect`-class and pass that instance around where it's needed instead. Right now, you will create a new instance in each method and on each call to those methods, which is pretty bad performance wise (and can easily exhaust your databases connection pool). That would also render your `Connect` class pretty pointless since you could just as well create your PDO instance in one place directly and use it directly. This is abstraction for no actual gain.

Comment: @nitrin0 - the xx IP is just the placeholder I'm using on SO.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - I was definitely take your side note into consideration.  I was just following what the tutorial was saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you use PDO's constructor:

```
parent::__construct("mysql:host='xx.xxx.x.xx:4485';dbname='myDb'", 'myDb_user', 'myDb_password')
```

...unless you want to connect to a host with the hostname `'xx.xxx.x.xx:4485` (which should be invalid, as the hostname should not include a colon)

Remove the quotes, add the port as another option:

```
parent::__construct("mysql:host=xx.xxx.x.xx;port=4485;dbname=myDb", 'myDb_user', 'myDb_password')
```

If you need additional configuration flags, see the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) for details about how to use them

Comment: I made the update you suggested, but now I am getting the following error: "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Comment: At least, that's a completely different error. Have you tried resolving it? SO contains some questions about that

Comment: @JohnBeasley - Make sure the IP and port is correct, that MySQL is up and running on that machine and that the firewall is configured to allow connections to the port MySQL is running on.

Comment: I changed the username and password to different username and password and I was able to connect.  Thank  you for your help.